# Calculate week no in google bigquery sql

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, week-number

Could anyone provide a code to calculate week no from current date in current quarter? E.g. today is Oct 6 2022, it lies in quarter 4, so week no is 1. Code should be in big query sql.

Comment: "it lies in quarter 4, so week no is 1"  The conclusion "so week no is 1" seems not to be a logical conclusion , please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Considering [13 weeks per quarter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month) and using ISO week number, you can try this:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - (13 * (EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE())-1))
```

Output:

```
1
```